# Moodle Scorm Course Resume

Tags: moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I am using Moodle 3.2.2 and I upload Scorm course Dispatch file in Moodle. Everything is working fine except Resuming course.

I created my own dispatch file like Scorm cloud does. When I test the same course by download Scorm cloud dispatch file its working fine. But My dispatch file in Moodle is not resuming the course.

Note:
I use iSpring Presenter to create SCORM course.

This is the dispatch structure of files I have.

[image]

The dispatch.html code is

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="configuration.js"></script>
    <script src="utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     include_script(DispatchRoot + "/scripts/client-driver.js");
        include_script(DispatchRoot + "/scripts/client-loader.js");

    </script>
</head>
<frameset id="dispatch_frameset" rows="0,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0" onload="DispatchStart('dispatch_course_frame')"
          onunload="DispatchUnload()">
    <!-- We set the src to blank.html to avoid security warnings in IE6 / IE7 when launching in HTTPS -->
    <!--<frame id="dispatch_content_frame" name="dispatch_content_frame" src="blank.html" />-->
    <frame id="dispatch_loading_frame" name="dispatch_loading_frame" src="blank.html" />
    <frame id="dispatch_course_frame" name="dispatch_course_frame">
</frameset>
<noframes>
    Your browser must be able to view frames for this content to display.
</noframes>

</html>
```

client-driver.js is a file which helps to build communication between LMS and SCORM. while client-loader.js file is where communication happens. I am using following code

```
var completionStatus = Getvalue("cmi.core.lesson_status");
            if (completionStatus == "not attempted") {
                SetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", "incomplete");
            }
            SetValue("cmi.core.exit", "suspend");
            console.log(Getvalue("cmi.core.student_id"));
            console.log(Getvalue("cmi.core.student_name"));
            var entry = Getvalue("cmi.core.entry")
            console.log(entry);
            if (entry == "resume") {
                var val = Getvalue("cmi.suspend_data");
                SetValue("cmi.suspend_data", val);
            }
            else {
                SetValue("cmi.suspend_data", "2");
            }
```

When the user close the Moodle LMS window this code execute

```
  SetValue("cmi.core.exit", "suspend");
    api.LMSCommit("");
    api.LMSFinish("");
```

But next time I am unable to resume course. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? How to resume course from the last slide.?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to dig this up from some real old knowledge so bare in mind you need to verify it.  I believe the way Moodle was coded; if you set any status it may trigger the SCO to re-launch in "Review" mode which will bugger up your cmi.core.entry. I had to explicitly setup a 'do not status until finish' option in my Content API Library to deal with this issue.  Do not confuse "Finish" with "LMSFinish".  Its more or less "the student is done with the attempt".  Most SCORM 2004 users set the status of the SCO to incomplete when its 'not attempted'.  It makes sense.  With one glaring difference - In SCORM 1.2 there is only one status for passed, failed, completed or incomplete (not attempted).
Check your `cmi.core.lesson_mode` to see if my theory is correct on a second launch.

As content developers we probably could have been doing a better job to expose UI elements to hit "I am done" like a turning in of your homework.  Some LMS systems even went to extents to put 'done' buttons in their TOC's or Lesson Viewers.
These terms often confuse people and some of it was addressed in SCORM 2004.  I believe Moodle abandoned their SCORM 2004 Runtime support.

Keep in mind Moodle also allows data to be set against a SCO in review mode.  SCORM didn't exactly dictate what a LMS should do in this situation, but Moodle opted to allow that to continue to change the student attempt. My opinion here is this is a "never ending attempt".  We could debate whether this is right/wrong or indifferent - but ultimately the SCORM white paper for 1.2 was mainly optional vs mandatory, and they didn't call out what a LMS should or shouldn't do on this.  We'd need a time machine to go back to 2001.